# how to access to globals in pug render

Tags: node.js, pug

i am using fastify with point-of-view module to render pug templates:

```
Fastify.register(require('point-of-view'), {
    engine: {
      pug: require('pug')
    },
    templates: Path.join(__dirname,'templates'),
    options: {
      filename: Path.join(__dirname,'templates/layout.pug'),
      globals: [
        {
          assets_path: 'Path_to_assets'
        }
      ]
    }
  })
```

how I can access to globals inside pug templates?

Answer (score 0):

well, I found a method: accessing to env vars.

in my templates I use

```
global.process.env.ASSETS_PATH
```

where ASSETS_PATH is declared as part of my env vars

Answer (score 0):

You can't access 'options' parameter. But you can pass your variable via defaultContext like this:

```
fastify.register(require('point-of-view'), {
  engine: {
    pug: require('pug')
  },


  defaultContext: {
    // Place your variable here
    globals: [],
    myVars,
    appName: 'Fastify Website'
  },


  templates: Path.join(__dirname,'templates'),
  options: {
    filename: Path.join(__dirname,'templates/layout.pug'),
    globals: [
      {
        assets_path: 'Path_to_assets'
      }
    ]
  }
})
```